# IndexError using stmplib in Python

Tags: python, smtp, imap

I am trying to forward out and delete certain emails from a gmail account and run the others through a separate process. I've been following [this example](http://stackp.online.fr/?p=42) but for some reason I am running into an `IndexError` that my `try` `catch` I included up for another issue (if the inbox is empty) picks up.

```
# Connect and login to email
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
imap.login('sender','password')
imap.list()
imap.select('inbox')

smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
smtp.login('sender','password')

try:
    result, data = imap.search(None,'ALL') # search and return sequential ids
    ids_list = data[0].split()
    print 'Total emails: '+str(len(ids_list))
    latest_id = ids_list[-1]

    #Process each email in inbox
    for i in ids_list:
        t, d = imap.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')
        for res_part in d:
            if isinstance(res_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_string(res_part[1])
                subject = msg['subject']
                print 'Subject: '+subject
        if subject != 'Subject of email I care about':
            print 'Dealing with it'
            #Forward email to another account
            #Attempt to forward an email
            text = res_part[0][1] #Something is wrong with this line, throws exception
            smtp.sendmail('sender', 'destination', text)
            imap.store(i, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
            imap.expunge()
        else:
            #Process email
            print 'Don\'t delete this'

except IndexError:
    print 'Error'
    #Inbox is empty (Or in this case apparently not)
```

I can't seem to figure out why I'm receiving this error. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your indenting correct as shown?  I would have expected the `if subject` line to be indented underneath the `if isinstance` line, but it isn't.

Comment: Duh! Wow, that was silly of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent the

```
if subject != 'Subject of email I care about':
            print 'Dealing with it'
            #Forward email to another account
            #Attempt to forward an email
            text = res_part[0][1] #Something is wrong with this line, throws exception
            smtp.sendmail('sender', 'destination', text)
            imap.store(i, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
            imap.expunge()
else:
            #Process email
            print 'Don\'t delete this'
```

If you don't, then `res_part` won't be a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is a typo in your indentation, because that is not the issue you have. You are making another mistake, using `res_part` however. In your code, you are looping over the data, `d`, using `res_part` as the element. Now, that means `res_part` will only contain part of `d` per iteration. Thus, it will be of lower dimensionality. You probably want something like:

```
# Connect and login to email
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
imap.login('sender','password')
imap.list()
imap.select('inbox')

smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com')
smtp.login('sender','password')

try:
    result, data = imap.search(None,'ALL') # search and return sequential ids
    ids_list = data[0].split()
    print 'Total emails: '+str(len(ids_list))
    latest_id = ids_list[-1]

    #Process each email in inbox
    for i in ids_list:
        t, d = imap.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')
        text = d[0][1]
        msg = email.message_from_string(text)
        subject = msg['subject']
        print 'Subject: '+subject
        if subject != 'Subject of email I care about':
            print 'Dealing with it'
            #Forward email to another account
            #Attempt to forward an email
            smtp.sendmail('sender', 'destination', text)
            imap.store(i, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
            imap.expunge()
        else:
            #Process email
            print 'Don\'t delete this'

except IndexError:
    print 'Error'
    # Probably won't happen for empty inbox either, as for loop will not execute
    # To catch an empty inbox you could you an `else:` construct.
    #Inbox is empty (Or in this case apparently not)
```

I haven't tested this code. Particularly I am assuming that your way of fetching the message from the data part works the way you have implemented it. Also, this does not test for the first element of `d`, i.e., `d[0]` being a tuple. I assume that, as that is assumed in the example you linked to.